# Unlimited sick day policy

Tags: human-resources, company-culture, company-policy, sickness, company

I am an HR coordinator and our company is adopting an unlimited sick day policy and we have never done that before. is there anyone can share your unlimited sick day policy? thank you.

Comment: You are HR in your company, about to enact policy that... you don't know? Ask whomever made that policy. Also VTC as this is offtopic, on google you can find many examples

Comment: I don't understand what an unlimited sick day policy is. How did you limit how many days people get sick in the past?

Comment: Hi Helena, thank you for your answer, we used to entitle employees 18 paid sick days per year and now the company is introducing unlimited sick days policy, which means that there is no limitation on how many sick days they want to take, but we want to have a policy guide employee correctly use their sick time instead of abusing it. we also want to understand what "unlimited" means to employees and how we are processing it. @Helena

Comment: @Helena Usually these unlimited sick day and vacation policies mean that there is no accrual (from a payroll perspective) to pay out if someone leaves, and that so-called unlimited time off is still subject to a manager's discretion.

Comment: @AidaPaul what is VTC in this context?

Comment: @RohitGupta Vote to close.

Comment: @AidaPaul  Hi Aida, we have not had this policy before, it is newly created topic and I want to know how we should word the policy and avoid misleading our employees and try to look for some examples.

Comment: Knowing the country and or state will help. Some jurisdictions dictate leave requirements. You have to make sure that any restrictions you place on leave still are legal.

Comment: Hi Mhoran, thank you for your comment. I am working in a small municipality in Ontario Canada, i was trying to do some research on google and found most examples from the U.S. and I have not been able to find any examples either from U.S. or somewhere else. and was wondering if anyone here can share their policy. Thank you.

Comment: Unlimited sick leave is an accounting issue, not an HR issue. The HR issue is educating the managers on how to measure performance (which will be different in the various departments). The goal is to have managers who can determine that the person who is always there isn't doing anything while the person there only half the time is doing 80% of the department's work (or it could be the other way around). That a person is using a lot of sick leave is meaningless unless it affects performance.

Comment: @DavidR  Hi David, thank you for the information. Before we implement the policy we need to consider the possible challenges it may cause, like abuse policy, like increase overtime or we have to hire more staff to cover shifts and complete work because employees call in sick. we want to communicate with managers.

Comment: Do employees need to document their sickness (e.g. doctor's note) or document it over a certain number of days?

Comment: when they are off for 3 days or longer and a doctor's note is required. @DJClayworth

Comment: Also what country are you in?

Comment: @WenqingLiu - "we also want to understand what "unlimited" means to employees and how we are processing it." - Ask your employees. Unlimited is unlimited, that can be with or without restrictions, but I have only heard of unlimited annual leave not sick leave.  Your question does not mention Canada.

Comment: I worked for an US employer who had unlimited sick+personal days. This worked well and on average people took 3.5 days/year. Of course, there is always the occasional idiot who blatantly abuses the system, so some sort of guidance and tracking policy is helpful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm from the Netherlands and "Unlimited" sick days are the norm here. Here it's normal to think "*If you're sick, you're sick and sick people stay home*". We have decent compensation if you are sick (at least 70% of your wage, most companies do 100% for the first 3 months).

What does this mean in practice? Nothing special. No mass sick leave or other abuse of those rules. Yes, there are *a few* people abusing this (eg. Monday morning sickness, aka hangover), but for the most part no abuse.

What happens is that when someone is sick, they stay at home and take a proper rest. Instead of people not wanting to lose sick days where they go to the office, are a week unproductive and might infect other people and/or become sick again, they stay home 2 or 3 days and then continue "fresh".

And when it turns out you have people abusing the system, you find the bad apples pretty quickly and now know who to replace.  In my experience it appears that often those people aren't your best workers anyway.

---

My definition of unlimited:
I can call in sick *now*, go home and stay home for as long as I like. If its more then a few days, more explanation is needed than "just feeling sick", but I can stay at home. When there is reasonable doubt, they can make me go to a doctor who specializes in deciding whether or not I can (partially) work. If that doctor says I'm legit, I can take sick leave easily a year+. Probably longer, but as that is *very* uncommon, I don't know the details at that timeline. Its worth noting that that doctor does lean towards getting people back into the workforce.

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing this information and very appreciated. I am wondering how your policy define "unlimited"?

Comment: I've added that to my answer

Comment: thank you for the information. Appreciated.

Comment: You can be sick a maximum of two years (you can be sick longer, obviously, but not as an employee), and after that UWV - assuming sufficient work has been done by employer and employee to reintegrate/get back to work, or there is good reason this was not possible - will grant the employer permission to fire the employee. The employee will then go into "ziektewet", and possibly WAO.

Comment: BTW: The clock on that 2 year period resets if an employee reported 100% better for a period of 4 weeks (without vacation). Also, if the UWV finds that not enough was done to get the employee back to work, they can fine the company and/or require them to employ the sick employee for longer.